# Advantages of using an rxjs subject in Angular form

Tags: angular, rxjs

I have the following simple template in Angular.

**component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-label">Liquid</label>
  <ng-select [items]="liquids$ | async" placeholder="Select Liquid" [(ngModel)]="selectedLiquid" (change)="onChangeLiquid($event)"></ng-select>
</div>

<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-label">Version</label>
  <ng-select [items]="versions$ | async" placeholder="Select Version"[(ngModel)]="selectedVersion"></ng-select>
</div>
```

When the user selects a liquid in the first `ng-select` I want to query the available versions for that selected liquid to populate the second `ng-select`.

I did have the following TypeScript file to handle this:

**component.ts**

```
...
export class LiquidComponent implements OnInit {
  liquids$: Observable<any[]> = this.liquidService.getLiquids();
  versions$: Observable<any[]>;
  selectedLiquid: any;
  selectedVersion: any;

  constructor(private liquidService: LiquidService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

  onChangeLiquid(event) {
    this.selectedVersion = null;
    this.versions$ = this.liquidService.getVersions(event.value);
  }
}
```

However it didn't feel very "reactive" and from reading various answers on here it seems I should be using rxjs Subjects to monitor changes. So I've changed it to this instead which seems to work fine...

**component.ts**

```
...
export class LiquidComponent implements OnInit {
  liquids$: Observable<any[]> = this.liquidService.getLiquids();
  versions$: Observable<any[]>;
  selectedLiquid: any;
  selectedLiquidSubject: Subject<any> = new Subject<any>();
  selectedVersion: any;

  constructor(private liquidService: LiquidService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.selectedLiquidSubject.subscribe(liquid => {
      this.selectedVersion = null;
      this.versions$ = this.liquidService.getVersions(liquid.value);
    });
  }

  onChangeLiquid(event) {
    this.selectedLiquidSubject.next(event);
  }
}
```

Is this any better? I'm using Subjects now but it seems a little bit more work and all of the logic is embedded into `ngOnInit` rather than into the change events. What are the advantages (if any) in doing it this way instead? Is there a cleaner/better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, this is not really "reactive" code.

Here's how you could achieve the same using reactive forms instead and in a reactive way:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  template: ``,
})
export class App {
  public liquidFc = new FormControl<string | null>(null);
  public versionFc = new FormControl<string | null>(null);

  public liquids$ = this.liquidService.getLiquids();

  public versions$ = this.liquidFc.valueChanges.pipe(
    switchMap((liquidSelected) =>
      !liquidSelected
        ? of(null)
        : this.liquidService.getVersions(liquidSelected)
    )
  );

  constructor(private liquidService: LiquidService) {}
}
```

Comment: I assume you know how to make a reactive form in the view. If not I can post the HTML later on today but I need to move now, hopefully that unblocks you for now.

Comment: Thanks, this is really interesting. I'm going to stick with template form in this instance though as it is in a legacy project that uses template forms everywhere else.

Comment: What would `LiquidService.getLiquids()` looks like in this scenario?

Comment: I don't know, you tell me :D I just assumed it returned an `Observable<string[]>`

Comment: Haha it's actually an array of objects rather than strings but I take your point. I guess I'm asking, based upon your comments in the answer by Picci, whether the service should use `Subjects` or just simply return the observable from HttpClient?

Comment: It really depends on what you want and how you implement things. My preferred way of doing that would be to have a layer for the state management and an effect fetching that data to put it in the store when needed. Then from the view, you'd only ever query the store and never worry about if it's going to have a side effect of making another HTTP call or not. So I wouldn't use subjects not return the observable directly from HttpClient. Although do note that if you're developing a tiny app, it may be overkill. If you're working on a medium/large scale app, then that'd be the way to go

Answer (score 1):

I do not think there is any advantage in the second approach, quite the contrary as you noticed: more work for the same result.

Where `Subject`s come handy is in the services injected by Dependency Injection mechanism.

In your case the code of the service would look something along these lines

```
export class LiquidService {
   private versionsSbj = new Subject<any>()
   public versionsObs = this.versionsSbj.asObservable()

   ...

   public getVersions(params: any) {
      // next, error and complete will be called on the Observer represented
      // by this.versionsSbj
      this.httpClient.post(params).subscribe(this.versionsSbj)
   }
}
```

Once you have such a service, you can react to changes notified by the `versionsObs` Observable directly in the template using the `async` pipe, like this

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label class="form-label">Version</label>
  <ng-select [items]="versions$ | async" placeholder="Select Version"[(ngModel)]="selectedVersion"></ng-select>
</div>
```

The advantage of this approach is that any time `getVersions` is called (by `LiquidComponent` or even other components), the view of `LiquidComponent` will be updated. And if more than one Component needs to be updated when a call to `getVersions` returns, with such an approach it is enough to inject the `LiquidService` service in those components and subscribe to `versionsObs` (either with the `async` pipe or by calling the `subscribe` method on the `versionsObs` in the `ngOnInit` method of the Components.

This approach is what sometimes is called **smart serviced and dumb components**.

Comment: Subscribe is where reactivity ends. Subscribing in a method is not a good idea IMO. I've made an answer to explain how to stay in a reactive way

Comment: @maxime1992 What would you do if you have more than one component that needs to get updated by the result returned by the call to the service `getVersions`? By subscribing via a `Subject` we are just multiplexing reactivity. Reactivity is there, it is just moved from the Observable returned by the remote http call (which can be subscribed by just one client) to the Observable represented by the Subject.

Comment: If there's any such need, there should be a persistence layer in between. If the application is complex, a good idea would be to have a proper state management solution like ngrx, if the project is tiny one could just create a service called LiquidFacade and put a caching layer here (make the call once and store it in a hot observable is one example). Or, if caching is something you need more globally, you could consider https://github.com/ngneat/cashew

Comment: @maxime1992 as far as I know ngrx uses Subjects to implement the store, which actually is a reactivity multiplexer

Comment: Maybe internally. Doesn't mean the intent for the end user needs to be the same. If you go this way, observables in rxjs aren't coded with a reactive pattern, it's imperative. The internal code shouldn't necessary reflect good practices of the public API

Comment: But doing this `public getVersions(params: any) { this.httpClient.post(params).subscribe(this.versionsSbj) }` in a method is definitely a bad practice. You lose the ability to work on the stream and either switchMap, concatMap, exhaustMap, etc if that method is called more than once and the first call hasn't finished

Comment: @maxime1992 If you need to switchMap, concatMap, exhaustMap, or anything, you can do this in the service method like `public getVersions(params: any) { this.httpClient.post(params).pipe(....).subscribe(this.versionsSbj) }`, not in the Component code. This is the essence of smart services and dumb components. This concept is illustrated in more details in [this article](https://medium.com/p/88d2789e408a) where the Component is in React but the service reflects the "smart service" design and could be utilized as such, with no change, also in an Angular app.

Comment: Well, if you've got that in a method just like in your example above, if you call a method, it'll produce a new observable. So no matter what you have in the pipe (switchMap, concatMap, etc), it'll be useless as you'll only ever have one value emitted per observable produced